# Rails model relations, has_one or belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, relational-database

I have two models:

Datacentre:

```
class Datacentre < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :provider

end
```

and Provider:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :datacentres

end
```

and in the datacentre table i have `provider_id` yet when I try to show it in a view I get this: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'providers.datacentre_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  'providers'.* FROM 'providers'  WHERE 'providers'.'datacentre_id' = 262 LIMIT 11`

it seems like it's reacting the opposite way?

View:

```
- Datacentre.find(:all, :order => " name ASC, country ASC", :conditions => "").each do |c|

  %tr
    %td= c.name
    %td= c.provider.name
    %td= c.country
    %td
      = c.address            
      = c.postcode
```

Comment: Check the 'datacentre_id' column is present in providers table or not.

Comment: there shouldn't be a datacentre_id column in the providers table as a provider could have many datacentres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datacenter models should look like:

```
class Datacentre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
end
```

and it should contain `provider_id`.

You view could lool like

```
- Datacenter.order([:name, :country]).each do |c|
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `has_one` to `belongs_to` in `Datacentre` module. Hope it'll help!

Comment: I've changed this but then i get this error: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: The problem is on this line: `%td= c.provider.name` You're trying to find `Datacentre` with provider column, but instead you need to find `Provider` name in `providers` table with the `id == provider_id`.

Comment: but i want to show all the datacentres even if they don't have a provider linked to them

Comment: So, you have some datacentres without providers in your table? If that, try to add `<% unless provider_id.nil? %> %td= c.provider.name <% end %>` So, Rails will try to find `provider.name` only if `provider_id` exists.

Answer (score 0):

`has_one` and `has_many` are both on the ownership side of the relationship, but `has_one` specifies that there can only be one of the owned things. Both of them should have a model on the other end of the relationship with `belongs_to`.

In your example, you have said that the Datacentre owns the Provider **and** that the Provider owns the Datacentre. It should instead be that the Datacentre `belongs_to` the Provider.

You'll also need a `provider_id` column in the Datacentre table.

Comment: I've changed this but then i get this error: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`